# using "include" like statement in pf.conf to include some parts from other files

Tags: freebsd, pfsense, pf

I want to be able to include some parts of my pf.conf from other set of files.

For example I will include "set timeout" vs like statements in another file.

Using anchors and "load anchor from file" statements will not help because anchor can not hold such GLOBAL OPTIONS.

Comment: May be you should write your own config generator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [m4](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=m4&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&format=html) as a preprocessor that produces your final pf.conf. Or you can even break your pf.conf into parts and then have a simplistic "preprocessor" cat those parts > /etc/pf.conf.

Answer (score 4):

As per the pf.conf man page:

```
Comments can be put anywhere in the file using a hash mark (`#'), and
     extend to the end of the current line.  Additional configuration files
     can be included with the include keyword, for example:

       include "/etc/pf/sub.filter.conf"
```

Source: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pf.conf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE

Comment: I could be mistaken, but the FreeBSD manual page for pf.conf does not seem to cover the include keyword.

Comment: Yup. I think you have to add an anchor at the appropriate place, and then call `load anchor anchor_name from "/etc/pf/sub.filter.conf"`

Comment: As of now, these lines do exist (current version of the man page: FreeBSD 10.3 June 29 2012). This answer works perfectly.

Comment: FreeBSD docs don't mention it until 9.0, which wasn't out when I answered this question. OpenBSD 4.9 was out then, and its pf.conf man page does have the include keyword. I probably didn't see the pfsense or freebsd tags and should have cited my source.